# How to install DDD on OS X

Tags: macos, assembly, osx-yosemite, ddd-debugger

I am trying to install DDD debugger on OS X Yosemite.
There is no Hombrew package for ddd anymore and I tried with downloading the source code for DDD and then running:

```
./configure && make
```

but this didn't work. I got an error saying:

```
creating cache ./config.cache
checking host system type... configure: error: can not guess host type; you must specify one
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Look in the `configure` script and the `config.log` to see how it wants to detect the host type and why it fails.

Comment: I somehow managed to install it with a homebrew but when I try to run it I get the following message:
Error: Can't find display

Even after editing sshd_config (x11Forwarding yes)

Comment: Not sure how `ssh` is involved ... anyway, check the value of the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

Comment: running echo $DISPLAY shows a blank line.

Comment: Set it to the correct value :) If you are logging in through ssh, then it should have been set automatically, but try a value of `:10.0`. For usual local display, try `:0.0`. Don't know how that works on OSX, though.

Comment: I already tried that but it just says "Can't open display: localhost:10.0"